# Create an Excel #VALUE! error with Office.js

Tags: office-js

In Excel, when you attempt to add a string and a number, it results in #VALUE! with a warning tool tip that says, "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type."  I would like to create a similar tooltip message within the sheet for my add-in when certain actions by the user are taken.  I understand how to set the values in a range and format the range.  However, in the RangeFormat docs:

https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/rangeformat

I'm not seeing a way to create a warning tooltip.  Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?  I've provided a ScriptLab gist here:

https://gist.github.com/brandonkoch6/fba234ceea5f476a6ab05a4da504035c

The setTooltip function is where that formatting logic would go.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to manually control the warning tooltips with the Excel API currently.

However, if you want to return an error in the cell and force a warning tooltip to appear, you could use the API to set the value of a cell to be an error formula, such as `"=#VALUE!"`. This value will always cause the green triangle to appear, with the appropriate error message on hover.

-Michael (PM for Office)

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks so much!